# Synology L2TP IPsec VPN not working with macOS Monterey

Tags: vpn, nas, synology-diskstation

First things first: My macbook with macOS Catalina still can connect to the same VPN server.

#### Problem: Connecting to the Synology L2TP/IPsec VPN Server not possible anymore on macOS Monterey

The error messages says, that the VPN server does not answer. The macOS vpn log only contains following lines:

```
Tue Aug 23 13:31:21 2022 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Tue Aug 23 13:31:21 2022 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Tue Aug 23 13:31:22 2022 : l2tp_get_router_address
Tue Aug 23 13:31:22 2022 : l2tp_get_router_address 10.110.10.1 from dict 1
Tue Aug 23 13:31:22 2022 : L2TP connecting to server 'vpn.myholydomainname.com' (1.2.3.4)...
Tue Aug 23 13:31:22 2022 : IPSec connection started
Tue Aug 23 13:31:22 2022 : IPSec phase 1 client started
Tue Aug 23 13:31:22 2022 : IPSec phase 1 server replied
Tue Aug 23 13:31:23 2022 : IPSec phase 2 started
Tue Aug 23 13:31:23 2022 : IPSec phase 2 established
Tue Aug 23 13:31:23 2022 : IPSec connection established
Tue Aug 23 13:31:23 2022 : L2TP sent SCCRQ
Tue Aug 23 13:31:43 2022 : L2TP cannot connect to the server
```

#### Further problem details

I have no troubles from the same network location with macOS Catalina on another computer. The scenario is reproducible also on other macOS devices with Monterey.

### What steps can I do to get some more error details?

I can't find any useful resource beside the Synology Knowledgebase article. Do anybody have some ideas or findings what someone can do in such situation?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
Go to VPN Server > L2TP/IPSec. Make sure the option Enable SHA2-256 compatible mode (96 bit) is unselected if your client has iOS 14/macOS Big Sur or above installed.1
```

Source: https://kb.synology.com/en-uk/DSM/tutorial/What_should_I_do_if_I_fail_to_set_up_an_L2TP_connection_to_nas

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The setting is already actived. Looks like this is not the problem. But I will try changing the MTU size on the client side to the setting of the NAS L2TP/IPSec MTU setting.